# unity apply item animation to character

Tags: unity, animation

I'm trying to change the attack animation of my player in relation to the attack animation for the item he has in his hand.

For example, the default attack animation of my player is *puching* and once he picked up a sword I want his attack animation to be *sword attack*, for a hammer a *hammer attack*, etc ..

I searched a lot on the internet but didn't find much, I saw a few post talking about `AnimatorOverrideController` but I'm not sure if it's what I need because it overrides every animation clip of the `AnimatorController`. In my case I just want to change the attack `Animation Clip`.

So if you cloud give me some tips about the right way to do it, I would really appreciate because I'm a bit confused.

Thanks

**Edit :** BTW, I'm in Unity 3d

Comment: Is this 2d or 3d?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I forgot to specif. It's 3D

Comment: Edit your question to indicate that please